# Why is the string version of getline a non-member function?

Tags: c++, string, std

The `getline` function has a [character version](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/getline/) that is a member function, as well as a [global version](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline/) that takes strings. Why aren't they both member functions? The current way makes it seems as though there isn't a string version.

Comment: While it might be counter intuitive at first, there are authors that support the idea that the most object oriented way of adding functionality to a class is by means of free functions. Read through this [Guru Of the Week #84](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/084.htm). The question might turn into, *why are some of the existing library member functions not free functions?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`istream& istream::getline(char* s, streamsize n)` is part of the stream interface.

`istream& getline(istream& is, string& str)` is an **extension** method from the `string` library (just like the `istream &operator>>(istream&, string&)`).

This design was probably chosen in order to decouple *iostreams* from *string*, as `fstream::open()` also does not take `std::string` arguments but rather `const char*`.

Answer (score 3):

Because the implementation of the iostream classes should not depend on strings.

Answer (score 1):

The trouble with stream library is that it's not well designed. In particular the member function `getline` shouldn't be there at all. The free function `getline` is he right one to use, it has several advantages: it's not a member function, it's safe, not working on raw buffers, and requires no guesswork.

It needs to be mentioned that both member- and free functions are part of istream public interface.